# Trace of operator defined on direct sum of two vector spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, trace

Clearly, if $A\colon V\to V$ is an endomorphism on a finite-dimensional vector space and $V$ is the direct sum of two vector spaces $V_1$ and $V_2$ such that $A(V_i)\subset V_i$, then
$$
\mathrm{Tr}\,A=\mathrm{Tr}\,A|_{V_1}+\mathrm{Tr}\,A|_{V_2}.
$$
I was wondering if this is also true in the infinite-dimensional case, possibly under certain restricting circumstances. It seems very plausible, but I couldn't find any reference online.

Comment: What is the trace of a linear operator on a infinite-dimensional vector space?

Comment: "Traces" of the restrictions to subspaces don't make literal sense unless the operator stabilizes the subspaces... maybe you meant to assume that? Or do you mean "trace" in an extended sense as in @Rammus' answer below? The distinction could conceivably matter...

Comment: @paulgarrett You are right, I totally forgot about that: All I had in mind was the equation $\sum_{i=1}^{n-m}v^iAv_i+\sum_{i=n-m+1}^{n}v^iAv_i$, where $v_1,\ldots,v_{n-m}$ is a basis of $V_1$ and $v_{n-m+1},\ldots,v_n$ is a basis of $V_2$, but of course, we need that $A(V_i)\subset V_i$ for the expression $\mathrm{Tr}\,A|_{V_i}$ to make sense (at least in the finite dimensional case). I think requiring that $A(V_i)\subset V_i$ for one $i$ is enough.

Comment: @paulgarrett Or did you mean something else by "stabilizing"?

Comment: @Filippo: do a search for 'trace class operator' to find out about trace in infinite dimension.  Your question in infinite dimension requires some care about convergence of series.

Comment: @Filippo, if $A(V_i)\subset V_i$ for both $V_i$, then $A$ really does restrict to an operator on each of $V_i$ separately. It is also true, as you comment, that if $A(V_1)\subset V_1$, then $A$ makes sense as a map on the _quotient_ $V/V_i$, so has a trace there, and trace of $A|_{V_1}$ plus the trace of $A|_{V/V_1}$ is the trace of $A$ on $V$. (This still does leave issues of convergence...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With respect to the decomposition we can write $A$ in block form
$$
A = \begin{pmatrix} A_{00} & A_{01} \\ A_{10} & A_{11} \end{pmatrix}
$$
where $A_{00} \in B(V_1)$, $A_{01} \in B(V_2, V_1)$, $A_{10} \in B(V_1,V_2)$, and $A_{11} \in B(V_2)$. That is $A \begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} A_{00} x + A_{01} y \\ A_{10} x + A_{11} y\end{pmatrix}$  Then supposing $V_1$ and $V_2$ are closed subspaces of some Hilbert space we can define and orthonormal basis for $V_1$, $\{e_{1,i}\}_i$ and an orthonormal basis for $V_2$, $\{e_{2,i}\}_i$ such that $\{(e_{1,i},0)\}_i \cup \{(0,e_{2,i})\}_i$ form an orthonormal basis for $V_1 \oplus V_2$. From which you can show that $\mathrm{tr}(A) = \mathrm{tr}(A_{00}) + \mathrm{tr}(A_{11})$.

Comment: Thank you! As far as I know, the trace in the finite-dimensional case is only defined for endomorphisms. However, I was not so sure about the more general Hilbert space case. You assume that $A(V_i)\subset V_i$ and that the $V_i$ are closed (such that the $V_i$ are also Hilbert spaces), because the trace is only defined for continuous **endomorphisms** on a Hilbert space, right?

Comment: Yes, trace class is usually defined as a subset of bounded operators from a Hilbert space to itself. I'm not assuming $A(V_i) \subseteq V_i$. This would only be the case if $A_{01} = A_{10} = 0$.

Comment: Now I understand, thank you! Not only did I learn something new about the infinite dimensional case, but also about the finite dimensional case!